# Package file (.wl) automatically changing symbols when opened

Tags: packages

If I open a .wl file and enter the symbol for the imaginary unit, or the double brackets you get when you surround `[[` with esc, when I close and open the file I just get `I` and `[[`. If I write `E` raised to `x` using superscript, it turns into `E^x`. Can it not?

Comment: Not an answer, just noting that unlike notebooks, `.wl` files are meant to be editable with any plain text editor. If you enter special characters, that significantly degrades the editability of the file with anything except the Mathematica GUI. I don't know if this behaviour can be turned off, but I think it is the correct default behaviour.

Comment: If you want to use special characters and "2D" formatting, consider using a notebook with an auto-generated package file.